# Why itemTpl does not recognize the css class?

Tags: css, extjs, touch

I'm trying to format each record I retrieve from a server by using a class (carousel-squares) defined in a css file. I need that each record appears inside a thumbnail in my view.
However, when I use it inside a div in my itemTpl, nothing appears. Why itemTpl does not recognize the class? If i use the class outside (in cls:) it is recognized.

The code I have in my dataview is the following:

```
      xtype: 'dataview',
                                    store: {
                                        autoLoad: true,
                                        fields: ['Title', 'Description', 'State'],                                      

                                        proxy: {
                                            type: 'ajax',
                                            url: 'ws/idea/GetByState.php?title=&page=1',
                                            reader: {
                                                type: 'xml',
                                                record: 'WebIdea',
                                                rootProperty: 'GetByStateResult'
    }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    styleHtmlContent: true,
                                    cls: 'carousel-squares',
                                    itemTpl: '<div class="carousel-squares"><h3>{Title}</h3><p>{Description}</p></div>',
                                    flex: 1
```

My css is the following:

```
.carousel-squares {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border: 2px solid #99cb39;
    width: 90%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px 5px;
}
```

Comment: When the items in defined by your template are rendered, do they actually have the class applied to them? Are the rules defined in your custom class getting overwritten by another class?

Comment: Hi, yes the class is applied. I don't think they are overwritten because the class defined in the cls is working. I don't understand what can be happening :(